# Retrieving all dxf values for all DBText

Tags: vb.net, autocad-plugin

I’m trying to obtain the layer, location, value, height, width and style for each DBText value in the current open drawing.  So far I've only been able to get `objectID`s.

```
Function SelectAllText(dbIn As Database) As ObjectIdCollection
    Using doclock = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.LockDocument
        Dim retIDs As New ObjectIdCollection
        Using tr As Transaction = dbIn.TransactionManager.StartTransaction
            Dim bt As BlockTable = dbIn.BlockTableId.GetObject(OpenMode.ForRead)
            For Each btrID As ObjectId In bt
                Dim btr As BlockTableRecord = TryCast(tr.GetObject(bt(BlockTableRecord.ModelSpace), OpenMode.ForRead), BlockTableRecord)
                For Each TRefID As ObjectId In btr
                    Dim te = TryCast(tr.GetObject(TRefID, OpenMode.ForRead), DBText),
                        tid = te.ObjectId
                    retIDs.Add(tid)
                Next
            Next
        End Using
        Return retIDs
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: I can see that you edited the question while I was typing an answer... now I'm not sure what you need here... you may consider expand the question. Cheers.

Comment: Your answer works perfectly.  I edited my post trying to provide clarity, since it was voted down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approache you proposed should work, basically in the same way: iterating through the Database>BlockTable>BlockTableRecord(ModelSpace)>All Entities.

With the ObjectId of each DBText you can:

```
Dim acText as DBText = tr.GetObject(dbTextId, OpenMode.ForRead)
Dim positionPoint as Point3d = acText.Position
Dim height as Double = acText.Height
Dim content as String = acText.TextString
```